# jstest-gtk not saving profile

Tags: games, gamepad

I'm currently still a beginner with Ubuntu and I'm having problems with jstest-gtk.

I've installed jstest-gtk and I've managed to setup my afterglow Xbox 360 wired controller how I want, however when I go to save to profile it tells me it has saved it as "Profile 0" then I close the window but when I reopen jstest-gtk my profile is no longer in the drop down menu but my controller is still setup to how I want. When I restart my computer either from shut down or reboot my I have to setup my controller all over again and there is still no profiles saved in the drop down menu still. It is really annoying having to setup my controller every time I start Ubuntu.

If anyone can help I'll truly grateful.

Answer (score 6):

After looking through the code, there doesn't appear to be any code to actually read the profiles. The profiles do get written to `~/.config/jstest-gtk/profile/profileX.xml`.

This nifty program is v0.1.1. I'm not sure where this version number came from as the original developer only released v0.1.0. Chances are that the developer just never got around to writing the profile read/load code. The project appears dead now, with the last change on Github being a typo fix a year ago.

So, ultimately, it'll be up to somebody else to actually implement the profile reading/loading functionality in the program. However, you can use the written `~/.jstest-gtk/profile/profile1.xml` as a reference to set the values as desired.

#### UPDATE

I have found a way to save these settings. Once you have your deadzones and everything configured in jstest-gtk, it automatically applies the settings using `jscal`. The joystick package that contains `jscal` also contains `js-store`, `js-restore` and udev rules for `js-restore`. So, in order to save your configuration you simply have to open a terminal and type this command:

```
sudo jscal-store /dev/input/js0
```

`/dev/input/js0` is my joystick, but yours may be different

After running this command, when plugging in your joystick/joypad `js-restore` will automatically run thanks to the udev rules which will automatically restore the joystick profile made with `jstest-gtk` and saved with `js-store` into the file `/var/lib/joystick/joystick.state`.

**See also**: [`jscal` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jscal.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

For my version of jscal, the command to save was actually:

```
sudo jscal-store /dev/input/js0
```

But thanks Githlar; you got me on the right track.

I got the command from the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jscal.1.html)

Comment: You are correct, that's for the heads up